# Play videoView on another activity

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have an ImageButton which plays the video I recorded. Everything works fine but the thing is I want to play the recorded video(resultvideo) on another activity. I'm new to Android Dev. could someone teach me how to do that, thanks!

Here's my code:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButton;

    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    VideoView resultvideo;
    MediaController mediacontroller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediacontroller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);

        resultvideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent(View v) {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);

            resultvideo.pause();

        }
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        {
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                    resultvideo.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send Uri of video via Intent to another activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("VIDEO_URI", videoUri.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

And then in Main2Activity in onCreate method get videoUri like this:

```
String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_URI");
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(uri);
```

Comment: I tried it, still won't work and the video wont play.

Comment: Sorry that must be right: `final Uri videoUri = data.getData(); if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { `

Comment: I don't have any errors but the video won't play on second Activity. That's what I meant sorry